# Itunesconnect remove tvOS version

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I just want to submit the iOS build to App Store. But I press wrong button to create the tvOS. I cannot remove the tvOS version. I search lots of reference also not work.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to delete the app. I want to remove the tvOS version

Comment: This is the worst - and oldest, bug. It has been reported since 2015 and Apple still didn't fix this.

Comment: I am getting the delete button, which spins but does nothing

Answer (score 9):

You can remove you tvOS Version , Just drag the mouse over that version (-) sign will appear to remove.

[image]

Comment: i tested right now and its working fine, may be you have some other issue. like you app information tab showing warning.

Comment: @NaumanMalik Do you already have an approved tvOS version? It seems like there is some pesky detail that you need an approved tvOS version in order to get the delete button to show. Even if I edit the html and manually show the button, deleting it will not succeed.

Comment: @esbenr i just created  TV app for test.

Comment: This button no longer exists.

Comment: Presently the delete option no longer exists. So what will be the alternative to delete the tvOS APP ?

Comment: @SURESHSANKE Delete button still exists.

Comment: Yes Nauman Malik. I can see that delete option.

Answer (score 8):

You must need to have admin access to be able to delete the tvOS App version

Comment: how can i delete the tvos version without any previous version?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Still work but it's a bit buggy, not always appears.

If not, reload the page or click on other section ("information of app", "Rating and comments", ...)

Comment: Deleted macOS app, but I can't delete tvOS app)

Comment: Weird logic, to delete tvOS app I need to create new version of iOS app (main) and now red minus button appeared.

Comment: @ChikabuZ thank you!!! this seems to be the only working solution.

Comment: It warns me as such "The resource can not be found" when I try to click red minus button, any ideas about what to do will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

add a new IOS version to your app and then you could remove the tvOS version by hoovering the mouse over it and then a little red remove button appeared on the right.